# Code Runner doesn't run code when I enable "Run in Integrated Terminal" option

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I've been using VS Code to run c++ with code runner on my chromebook for 2 months, and I had no issues.
Now I installed VS Code on my main Windows PC and I correctly installed the latest versions of g++ and gdb, in fact, VS Code compiles with no error every code.
The problem comes when I enable the setting "Whether to run code in Integrated Terminal", VS Code compiles but when I run code it doesn't do anything. I already searched on this forum but didn't find any correct answer so I prey you to help me, at least.
Obviously I'm talking about EVERY program, even "Hello World", if I enable that option and then run the code, it doesn't do anything and my output is empty.

Comment: Does it show any errors? In status bar or somewhere else?

Comment: Nothing at all, but thank you for the comment. Anyway, if someone has my same problem, I just solved by switching to an older version of code runner (you can do it in the extension panel) and it works! So I don't think the problem was mine.